# I am having a problem understanding this code

Tags: python

```
# Split string method
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
names = names_string.split(", ")
#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this line 
import random

num_items = len(names)
random_choice = random.randint(0, num_items - 1)
person_who_will_pay = names[random_choice]
print(person_who_will_pay + " Is going to pay the bill!")
```

**I have took 100 days of code from angela Yu from udemy I am currently in the random module Day-4 but i did not understand this code can anyone explain me what is going on with this code Please.**

Comment: What exactly are you struggling to understand?

Comment: This code takes a comma separated string of names, stores them in ```names``` list and picks up a random name from ```names``` list and then prints that random name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
# Gets input from the user as a string type.

names = names_string.split(", ")
# Splits the input string into a list of names.
# If names_string = "John, Mark, Mary", names = ["John", "Mark", "Mary"]


import random

num_items = len(names)
# Gets number of names in the list

random_choice = random.randint(0, num_items - 1)
# Selects a random index in the array from 0 to (number of names - 1)

person_who_will_pay = names[random_choice]
# Gets name stored at the chosen index.

print(person_who_will_pay + " Is going to pay the bill!")
# Prints person's name
```